# how to write a C# function to add arg of this class?

Tags: c#

very basic question I think.

```
 public class person {
    public string name;
    public int status;
    public int ability;

    public person() { }
    public person(string name, int status, int ability)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.ability = ability;
    }

    public static int praise() {
        return ++status;
    }
}
```

I want write a class with C#, it has a function to add every new class their 'status'. but there is a error because 'status' is not static . how can i solve this problem? thank you very much.

Comment: the obvious answer would be make it static, whether thats what you want or not is another matter

Comment: I think you should decide well your class design first. praise() being static means status would be a common property of all people, and not a status of a single person. If you intend it to be for a single person, then you probably don't want it to be neither a static method nor a static property.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to make `praise()` increment the status of the specific person, which means it shouldn't be a static method.

```
public int praise() {
    return ++status;
}
```

to call it you do

```
Person bob("bob", 0, 0);
bob.praise();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `static` modifier from the method declaration:

```
public int praise() {
    return ++status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to increment a member variable in a static method.  I'm going to assume that you don't want the praise() method to be static.  If that is the case, you can just change the praise() method to:

```
public int praise()
{
    return ++status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
public int praise(){
    return ++status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends what you are trying to acheive.

if you make `status` static all the instances of your class will share the same status variable:

```
public static int status;
```

if you don't make it static each instance of your class will have its own `status` variable

```
public int praise() {
    return ++status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making your field static?

```
public static int status;
```

Also do note that you should use properties instead of public fields...

---

Another thing is, you set the `status` field in the constructor of your class. So it's very confusing about the role of the `status` field. Do you actually want to share it between multiple instances or not?

If the `status` field is **not** common for all of your instances, then your `praise` method could take a collection of `person` as parameter, and increment their `status` one by one.

Maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: this is probably not what he wants, this means every person has the same status, as opposed to having every person have their own status.

Comment: @Hans, yes see updated question. Actually it's not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a non-static field in a static context.  You could make it static but that is up to your design.

Comment: `You can't reference a static field in a non-static contex` yes you can, that's backwards. You can't access a non-static field in a static context.

Comment: @vcsjones: Yes that is correct.  I've only drank about an ounce of coffee so my brain is still only partially functional ;)